# HttpClient SendAsync and return object will trigger two times

Tags: c#, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I have below code which use `HttpClient` and use `SendAsync`, when I test, it always run twice on API.

Controller :

```
[HttpGet("GetAllStores")]
public async Task<bookstores> GetAllStores()
{
   Console.writeline("Trigger Stores")
   return await dbContext.set<bookstores>().toListAsync()
}
```

HttpClient:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<bookstores>> FetchAllStores()
    {
        var requestContent = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Get
        };
        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync("http://127.0.0.1:5000/GetAllStores", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<bookstores>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(), defaultJsonSerializerOptions);
    }
```

Test:

```
    public async Task GetSettingProfile_AsExpected()
    {
        var sut = new ApiClient(
            new HttpClient() { BaseAddress=new Uri("http://localhost:40331") });
       
        await sut.FetchAllStores();
    }
```

The output in console is show Trigger Stores two times

Can I know how to make it which call API in one time?

Comment: Just use swagger to test my api, it only run one time only

Comment: Please post a minimal, reproducible example.